# How to handle signal flood from another thread in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, video-streaming, kinect

tl;dr: I have a QThread which sends a signal to the main thread whenever new data is available for processing. Main thread then acquires, processes and displays the data. The data arrives more often the the main thread is able to process it resulting in frozen GUI and eventually a stack overflow (yay!).

**Details**

My application acquires frames from a camera for processing and displaying. The camera notifies when the new frame is available through a windows event. I have a thread which periodically checks for these events and notifies the main thread when new frame is available for grabs:

```
void Worker::run()
{
    running_ = true;

    while (running_)
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject(nextColorFrameEvent, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)        
            emit signalColorFrame();        

        usleep(15);
    }
}
```

`signalColorFrame` is connected to a slot in `Camera` class which gets the frame from camera, does some processing and sends it to `MainWindow` which draws it to the screen.

```
void Camera::onNewColorFrame()
{    
    getFrameFromCamera();
    processFrame();
    drawFrame();
}
```

Now if that method completes before the next frame is available, everything works fine. As the processing gets more complex though the `Camera` class receives new signals, before it's done with processing a previous frame.

My solution is to block signals from the worker thread for the time of processing and force the even loop to run in between with `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`:

```
void Camera::onNewColorFrame()
{   
    worker_->blockSignals(true)
    getFrameFromCamera();
    processFrame();
    drawFrame();
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(); // this is essential for the GUI to remain responsive
    worker_->blockSignals(false);
}
```

Does that look like a good way of doing it? Can someone suggest a better solution?

Comment: Ok, I removed the part about this solution being unreliable, as that was due to my mistake. It pretty much works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

I think before you solve technical side you should consider to think about design side of your application. There are several ways your problem can be solved, but first you should decide what to do with frames which you dont have time to process in main thread. Are you going to skip them or save for later processing, but then you should realise that processing queue still must have certain size limits, so you anyway should decide what to do with 'out of bound' data.

I would personally prefer in such cases make some intermediate container which holds data which received somewhere, so your camera processing thread just notify collector that data received and collector decides if its going to store or skip data. And main loop as soon as it has time access collector in a form fetchNext() or fetchAll() depending on what you need and implements object processing.

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking about this. They way it works currently is just to not accept new frames until the last one has been processed, then get the one currently available (so the newest one). This is for the real-time data. I'll also have offline processing, where solution similar to the one you suggest will be more appropriate.

Comment: In that way I dont think you need to emit signals at all. Why you should notify something which decides on it's own then it has processing time available. So instead of signalling and passing across application data which will be thrown away isn't better to store latest frame in your Camera object and make thread safe method , something like getLatestFrame(), so main thread as soon as it has no job will check is Camera has something to process...

Comment: The worker thread only signals new frame availability, it doesn't pass any data. The data is retrieved in the main thread (that's were Caera object lives). The reason I need a worker thread for that is that the loop continuously checking if an event has occurred would block the GUI otherwise.

Comment: Well, then I would post event rather then emitting signal. For different reasons I dont think that sending signals between threads is a good idea. At least use Queued connection type. (but that's actually a signal/slot mechanics wrapper over events)

Comment: I have no idea how to deal with events in Qt though. If I post event how do I handle it without message loop?

Comment: Why you consider not to have a message loop? =)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28574/discussion-between-evilruff-and-marian)